# Send string[] data to api Angular 4

Tags: angular

I want send property model, example i already selected data from table have a model JSON array { a: string, b: object, c:string} but i want to send only property c.

this is my function

```
public onApprove(mf) {
     if (mf === null || mf.undefined) return;
     if (!this.btnControl) { return; }

     this.btnControl = false;
     let data: Array<string> = [];
     const approvalLeader = new ApprovalL1Model();
     data = mf.data.filter(f => f.isSelector == true);
     data.push(approvalLeader.groupId);

     this.approvalLeaderService.approve(data)
         .subscribe(
             s => {
             },
             e => {
                 this.btnControl = true;
                 this.alertService.error(e.status, e.statusText, e._body);
             });
     this.getData();
     console.log(data);
     this.btnControl = true;
     this.alertService.success('Booking Approved');
}
```

I already try but my `data.push` value was undefined, any solution?

Comment: cant you simply loop it & pickup `c` pass it on server by storing in a new array(temp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using rxjs `map` operator you can acquire that. First of all, collect your object property, after it send it to api. e.g.:

```
   let array = data.map(object => {return object.c});
```

Comment: i have a model approvalL1model how to include the model to data.map()?

Comment: can i see declaration of approvalModel?

Comment: groupId: string; dtoBooking: bookingmodel[];

Comment: i mean. this will return undefined your code. because you didn't initialize your object. if you need just groupId you can acquire it with `approvalLeader['groupId']`

Comment: let array = data.map(f => { return approvalLeader['groupID']} );
like this?

Comment: why does it needs to be an array? did you initialize your approvalLeader object? if not, you will get undefined anyway

Comment: ok sir i already initialize approvalLeader Object and it works. thank you sir

Comment: i try like this and it works         let a = this.approvalLeaders.map(f => { return f.groupID})